# youtube-dl - how to increase buffer size

Tags: youtube-dl

I download youtube videos on my raspberrypi 24/7 I am looking at a way to reduce the number of writes to the SD card.

I know the option --buffer-size SIZE (1024 or 16K). But that does not reduce the number of writes to the SD card even when I give the parameter 1024k.

Is there any option to buffer the downloaded bytes (up to 10MB or 50MB) and then write to disk/card?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to increase buffer size in youtube-dl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472169/how-to-increase-buffer-size-in-youtube-dl)

Comment: This question was removed

Answer (score 0):

use `maxBuffer: Infinity` in youtube-dl library

```
var video = youtubedl('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0h-qh9flX2A', ['-f=best'], {cwd: __dirname, maxBuffer: Infinity} )
```